# Override inherited property or make a new one if more specific?

Tags: c#

I have a `weapon` class, `projectile` class and `ballistic weapon` class that inherits from `weapon`, `ballistic projectile` class inherits from `projectile` and  `weapon` class has a projectile property that gets and sets the projectile for the weapon.

ballistic weapon inherits this however ballistic weapon wouldn't have just any weapon
it has a ballistic projectile (distinct from say a laser projectile that wouldn't have a projectile speed because it is instant impact)

So if I choose to override the property of weapon, the setter could cause issues because

```
public Projectile weaponprojectile
{
// getter/setter
}
```

takes just a generic Projectile. The getter override would work ok because returning a ballstic projectile is still returning a base projectile, it has all the things projectile does and then some. However the setter wouldn't absolutely be ok. Not just any projectile can be set as a ballistic projectile.

So if I use an override is it the right way to confirm the type of ballistic and static convert or should I try something else?

If i don't use a override but make a new setter I'm worried I'd end up with this weapon that had 2 nearly indentical properties,

its projectile and its ballistic projectile which is basically a projectile plus some other stuff and really having a get ballistic projectile is pointless.

I'm new to using inheritance so if someone could give me guidance basically on what you do if you have an abstract class with a generic variable and you inherit that class and variable and have a more specific type of variable.

Comment: Can you post code sample,please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/covariance/info) to allow for "specialized" projectiles in weapon properties, while still keeping the ability to treat the weapons as part of the same hierarchy:

```
interface IProjectile {
    string Name { get; }
}

// Note the `out` keyword below:
interface IWeapon<out TProjectile> where TProjectile : IProjectile {
    TProjectile Projectile { get; }
}

class BallisticMissile : IProjectile {
    public double Speed { get; set; }
    public string Name { get { return "ballistic missile"; } }
}

class BallisticWeapon : IWeapon<BallisticMissile> {
    public BallisticMissile Projectile { get; set; }
}

class LaserBeam : IProjectile {
    public double WaveLength;
    public string Name { get { return "laser beam"; } }
}

class LaserWeapon : IWeapon<LaserBeam> {
    public LaserBeam Projectile { get; set; }
}

class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        // Manipulate the ballistic weapon in its own specific way:
        var ballisticWeapon = new BallisticWeapon();
        ballisticWeapon.Projectile = new BallisticMissile();
        ballisticWeapon.Projectile.Speed = 2000;

        // Manipulate the laser weapon in its own specific way:
        var laserWeapon = new LaserWeapon();
        laserWeapon.Projectile = new LaserBeam();
        laserWeapon.Projectile.WaveLength = 400;

        // But you can still use both of them as an IWeapon<IProjectile>:
        var weapons = new List<IWeapon<IProjectile>>();
        weapons.Add(ballisticWeapon);
        weapons.Add(laserWeapon);
        foreach (var weapon in weapons)
            Console.WriteLine(weapon.Projectile.Name);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this post I thought it was a clever use of covariance I had not considered (or maybe I just didn't understand the deep applications of covariance :)).  
For my own edification wouldn't this approach mean that if you wanted to expand IWeapon later with something like TExplosion you would have to visit every implementation of IWeapon in the project?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @MattJohnson Well, whenever a new member is added to an interface, all classes implementing that interface must be amended to implement that new member, regardless of covariance.

Comment: So if we were looking for future expansion would you recommend moving the <out TProjectile> to BallisticWeapon and leave IWeapon a simple interface, or would that mess up the benefits of covariance?

Comment: @MattJohnson Only interfaces (and delegates) support co(ntra)variance, so you wouldn't be able to use `out` keyword in the type parameter list of a generic _class_. My first instinct would be to just add `TExplosion` as a type parameter of `IWeapon` and add appropriate properties/methods there. If you are only reading `TExplosion` you can make it covariant. If you are just writing it, you can make it contravariant. If both, it must be invariant.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to design what you are looking for.  If it was me I would probably make use of interfaces to avoid the inheritance issues you are describing.  I may also make these different types of weapons described in an xml file that gets loaded at runtime.  However something like this would work base of what you are describing:

```
public interface IWeapon
    {
        int WeaponDamage { get; }
    }

    public interface IBalisticWeapon
    {
        int BallisticDamage { get; }
    }

    public interface IProjectile
    {
        int ProjectileDamage { get; }
    }

    public abstract class WeaponBase: IWeapon
    {
        public virtual int WeaponDamage { get { return 100; } }//base damage
    }

    public class Arrow : WeaponBase, IProjectile, IBalisticWeapon
    {
        public override int WeaponDamage { get { return this.BallisticDamage; } }

        public int BallisticDamage { get { return 10; } }

        public int ProjectileDamage { get { return this.BallisticDamage; } }
    }

    public class BattleAxe : WeaponBase
    {
        //this inherits Weapon Damage from WeaponBase
    }

    public class Rock : WeaponBase, IProjectile
    {
        public override int WeaponDamage { get { return this.ProjectileDamage; } }
        public int ProjectileDamage { get { return 10; } }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static WeaponBase GetWeapon()
        {
            return new Arrow();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int damage = 0;
            IWeapon weapon = GetWeapon();
            if (weapon is IProjectile)
            {
                damage = (weapon as IProjectile).ProjectileDamage;
            }
            else if (weapon is IBalisticWeapon)
            {
                damage = (weapon as IBalisticWeapon).BallisticDamage;
            }
            else
            {
                damage = (weapon as IWeapon).WeaponDamage;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to post all classes involved. If I understand you I would think you have some Fire method in the Weapon class (or some method that uses weaponprojectile). You probably want to override that method. Having to detect the type and take an action is not the best design. It is better to encapsulate what changes (in this case the code doing the Fire/Attack/Whatever) and the Setter. Example

```
public class BalisticWeapon
{
  public BalisticWeapon(){}

  public override BalisticProjectile weaponprojectile
  {
    get { return Base.weaponprojectile; }
    set { Base.Weaponprojectile = value; }
  }

  public override void Fire()
  {
    //Handle special case for Firing BalisticProjectile
  }
}
```